# Why is this javascript Array() producing an array with only one element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function in a next js app:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    const campaign = campaignInstance(ctx.params.address);
    const requestCount = await campaign.methods.getRequestsCount().call();
    
    console.log(requestCount);
    console.log(Array(requestCount).fill());

    // this is what I'm actually trying to do...
    // I cannot return an entire array of structs from 
    // a Solidity smart contract so I get each element individually.

    const requests = await Promise.all(
        Array(requestCount).fill().map((element, index) => {
            return campaign.methods.requests(index).call();
        })
    );

    return {
        props: {
            requests: JSON.stringify(requests),
            address: ctx.params.address
        }
    };
}
```

Which outputs this to my console:

```
4
[ undefined ]
```

I should see an array with 4 undefined elements, right? It is clear that `requestCount` is evaluating to 4.

Comment: Are you sure it’s a `4` and not a `"4"`?

Comment: You don't generally preallocate an array's length in JS, because JS arrays aren't like statically typed arrays. You define an empty array, then you start adding in content either by stack pushing, or by setting explicit indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Sebastian's comment: your `requestCount` is almost certainly a string instead of a number:

```
new Array(4).fill()
// Array(4) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

new Array("4").fill()
// Array(1) [ undefined ]
```

In fact the second constructor [does something *wildly* different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) from the first one. `new Array(int)` will create an Array with `<int>` empty slots. However, `new Array(not-an-int)` will create an array with the constructor arguments as content, so:

```
new Array(4)
// Array(4) [ <4 empty slots> ]

new Array("4")
// Array(1) ["4"]
```

So if we call `.fill()` without any argument, we're saying "replace the content for all elements with `undefined`", and we have an array containing a single element (the string "4"), then we end up with `[undefined]`.

The lesson here is to *always* validate your inputs before you pass them to functions/constructors that are polymorphic with respect to argument type:

```
const requestCount = await campaign.methods.getRequestsCount().call();

// I don't know what that line can return, so verify that there even
// _is_ a result. If there is, then we can continue:

const n = parseInt(requestCount);

if (isNaN(n)) {
  // this is a probably something you should have a contingency for
}

// and if n _is_ a number, it also needs to make sense as an array length value
else if (n > 0) {
  const mapped = [...Array(n)].map((_,i) => {
    // do something with i
  });
}
```

But that "convenient syntax" using map basically wastes time on creating an array that we're then immediately throwing away. That's silly: we can achieve the exact same result without immediately invoking garbage collection by using array's stack functions:

```
// note: let, not const, because we're going to run it down to 0
let n = .....

...code that returns early based on bad values of n...

const mapped = [];
while(n--) {
  // since we're running our index backwards, we use unshift(),
  // which is like push() but for the start, not end, of an array.
  mapped.unshift(campaign.methods.requests(n).call());
}
```